# Issue with class cast exception between subclasses and collections in Java

Tags: java, generics, collections, casting

So, I have the following two classes:

```
Class A { }
Class B extends A { }
Class C extends A { }
```

And the following method:

```
public void foo(Collection<A> bar) {
    List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();

    for(A a : bar) {
        //a and anotherA are both of the same subtype of A
        A anotherA = getAnotherA(a);
        listA.add(anotherA);
    }

    bar.clear();
    bar.addAll(listA);
}
```

Now, I am trying to call this method two separate ways, but I cannot get the casting to work properly... Hopefully I am just overlooking something small.

So, here are the two ways I am calling it:

Way 1:

```
A obj = ...;
Field field = //get field representing a collection of sub-type of A
Collection<A> collection = field.get(...);
foo(collection);
```

way 2:

```
B obj = ...;
Set<C> setOfC = b.getSetOfC();
foo(setOfC);
```

I have tried numerous casting attempts, but I cannot seem to get it to compile!  For instance, in way 2, I tried casting `setOfC` to `Set<A>`, but I get a class cast exception.  I have tried to cast `bar` to `Collection<? extends A>`, but then bar.addAll(..) fails.  I have tried to add a generic to foo, but also get errors.  In way 1, I have also tried to cast `collection` to `Collection<? extends A>`, but still not luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a `Set<C>` into a method expecting a `Collection<A>`, even though a `Set` is a `Collection`, and even though a `C` is an `A`, because Java's generics are invariant.

You can introduce a type parameter on the `foo` method, with an `A` upper bound.  Then you can use the type parameter throughout the method.  This will ensure that the same subtype of `A` is used.

```
public static <T extends A> void foo(Collection<T> bar) {
    List<T> listA = new ArrayList<>();

    for(T a : bar) {
        //a and anotherA are both of the same subtype of A
        T anotherA = getAnotherA(a);
        listA.add(anotherA);
    }

    bar.clear();
    bar.addAll(listA);
}
```

Your comment seems to indicate that `a` and `anotherA` are of the same type, so this should compile for you.  If not, then the `getAnotherA` method will need some work so that passing in a `C` will return a `C` and not an `A`.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I had tried this before as I figured it would be the correct approach, but remember getting an error.  I just tried it again and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

if you have this classes:

```
Class YourA { }
Class YourB extends YourA { }
Class YourC extends YourA { }
```

your method's signature most be like

```
public <G extends YourA> void foo(Collection<G> bar) {...}
```